# Rotate image after clicking the button - Android app

Tags: java, android

I developed an application that allows the user to access the camera phone and after taking a picture update the picture in ImageView.

My phone always updates the mirror image, so I created a button that rotates the image 90 degrees and another button that returns the image to the home position.

How do I program only a button and each has to click the image rotates 90 to 90 degrees?

**My function button**

```
public void rotateImage(View v)
{
    img.setRotation(90);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try hook up individual listener to each button like this.

```
        //--- find both the buttons---
        Button sButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_s);
        Button lButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_l);

        // -- register click event with first button ---
        sButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               rotateImage(v);
           }
        });

        // -- register click event with second button ---
        lButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               //do something else
           }
        });
```